# How to get an array of all sub-entries of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Is it possible to get an array of all *subentries* with a certain name of an array? For example, I have this array:

```
var array = [
  {
     "char": "a",
     "number": 5
  },
  {
     "char": "x",
     "number": 9
  },
  {
     "char": "u",
     "number": 2
  },
  {
     "char": "q",
     "number": 4
  }
];
```

How can I then get an array of all *number* (or all *char*) entries like this?

`*returned array* = ["a", "x", "u", "q"];` or `*returned array* = [5, 9, 2, 4];`

A simple (one-line) solution would be most helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var newArray = array.map(x=>x.number)`

Comment: That's easily done with a plain old `for` loop...

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You're expected to try and solve the problem yourself before asking. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the values depending on what you specify.

```js
var array = [
  {
     "char": "a",
     "number": 5
  },
  {
     "char": "x",
     "number": 9
  },
  {
     "char": "u",
     "number": 2
  },
  {
     "char": "q",
     "number": 4
  }
];
var result = array.map(x => x.char);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will do the trick...

```js
var array = [
  {
     "char": "a",
     "number": 5
  },
  {
     "char": "x",
     "number": 9
  },
  {
     "char": "u",
     "number": 2
  },
  {
     "char": "q",
     "number": 4
  }
];

var numbers = array.map(function(el) { return el.number; });
var chars = array.map(function(el) { return el.char; });

console.log(numbers);
console.log(chars);
```

Comment: As demonstrated in the duplicate

Comment: @Andreas I've demonstrated it exactly as asked.  There's nothing wrong with that, but feel free to downvote if you think this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a variable for the wanted key and map the values.

```js
var array = [{ char: "a", number: 5 }, { char: "x", number: 9 }, { char: "u", number: 2 }, { char: "q", number: 4 }],
    key = 'char',
    result = array.map(o => o[key]);
    
console.log(result);
```